# Enumerate all controls inside window

Tags: c#, winapi, user32, spy++

I'm trying to enumerate all controls inside a window using `user32.dll`, but I don't know exactly what I need to do.

I'm using `EnumWindows` and `EnumChildWindows`, but it doesn't retrieve all controls inside a window.

I want to get the text of some labels in a Delphi application.

I tried using Spy++, but it doesn't list too.

Comment: Delphi uses custom controls to an extent that EnumChildWindows will not work. Unfortunately I don't know if there's a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IList<IntPtr> childern = new List<IntPtr>();
    WNDENUMPROC enumChildProc = delegate(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr param)
    {
        childern.Add(hwnd);
        return true;
    };
    EnumChildWindows(Hwnd, enumChildProc, IntPtr.Zero);
    return childern;
```

which `Hwnd` is the parent window handle

Comment: I'm doing something like this, but doesn't retrieve all controls inside a Form.

Comment: @Alexandre Vicenzi: Are you sure this controls are really windows ?

Comment: I think it's the component. I've made a small app in C# and works right.

Comment: I in my idea, it can be because of that the application is not Win32 or Win64. It could be WPF app, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Delphi labels are non-windowed. That means that you cannot ever hope to obtain window handles for them since they are not windows.

If the Delphi VCL properly supported automation then you'd be able to use UI Automation to inspect the text of these controls. But the VCL only supports automation by dint of the underlying Win32 controls doing so. Since labels aren't windowed controls, again you are out of luck.

The only thing that can realistically hope to read this text is Delphi code inside the process. It does not sound as though that will be viable for you.